# How can you pass a Promise executor data?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Is there a way to bring **params** into the body of the Promise without depending on a closure?  I'd prefer not to have to use a `var self = this;`

```
function Service(n) {
    this.n = n;
}
Service.prototype = {
    get: function (params) {
        var self = this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            if (params[self.n]) {
                resolve("Service " + self.n);
            } else {
                reject("Service " + self.n);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: tagged es6, use arrow function

Comment: If your function is not asynchronous, why would you want to return a promise?

Comment: @hege_hegedus because of the interface?

Comment: @hege_hegedus I'd rather not include all of the async code to go along with this.  It's just an example.  Also other steps in the process are async.

Comment: @zero298: Ok, that's reasonable. I just wanted to make sure you are not making this function unnecessary async. sry about that

Comment: @zerkms: good point, but if I had an api to design, I would not require the consumers of the api to provide functions that always return promises. That would prevent them using already written synchronous code. Also that's the reason es7 `await` accepts non-promises as well.

Comment: @hege_hegedus well, from the design perspective and type system - you must return the value of the same type (that's what languages with strong typing would require you). From that perspective in my code the function either always returns a promise or something else.

Comment: @zerkms +1 for mentioning type safety. You are totally right, but I still can't risk `TypeError: x.then is not a function` just because someone put in a sync code as callback. Also, don't forget about thrown synchronous errors. Those should be rejections too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually may instead a create immediately resolved/rejected promise instead:

```
Service.prototype = {
    get: function (params) {
        if (params[this.n]) {
            return Promise.resolve("Service " + this.n);
        }

        return Promise.reject("Service " + this.n);
    }
}
```

References:

- [MDN - `Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)
- [MDN - `Promise.reject()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want. This basically avoids creating a new Promise correct?

Comment: Well, it creates a promise, but that is already resolved with a given value.

Comment: Ok, and I'd be making a Promise anyway from with the **get**.

Comment: Yep. When you don't have anything asynchronous in the promise constructor body - it's a sign you don't need it and do what I suggested instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can get around the extra `var self = this` by using an arrow function.

From the [Arrow Function MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a
>   shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds
>   the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target). Arrow functions are always anonymous.

Here is how it would be used in your example:

```
function Service(n) {
    this.n = n;
}
Service.prototype = {
    get: function (params) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (params[this.n]) {
                resolve("Service " + this.n);
            } else {
                reject("Service " + this.n);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That works well, but I'd prefer to not use arrow functions in this project just yet.  Could this be accomplished with a `function.bind()` in the same way?

Comment: @zero298 Closures are better than bind, except when instantiating a class with rest params. `new A(...args)` <=> `new (A.bind.apply(A, [null].concat([args])))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use ES7 `async` functions.

```
function Service(n) {
    this.n = n;
}
Service.prototype = {
    get: async function (params) {
        if (params[this.n]) {
            return "Service " + this.n;
        } else {
            throw "Service " + this.n;
        }
    }
}
```

I think there is nothing wrong about closures. This code will in fact transpile to code that relies on closures.